# How to reset the furthest page read on kindle devices

Tags: kindle

I was navigating through a kindle book on my mac, and flipped to one of the last pages by mistake.  I have an iPad, an actual Kindle, and a Mac that all want to sync to the acknowledgements section of this book now, and seemingly no way of undoing this.  I've searched online and found some random work-arounds, but I guess I'm looking for something more definitive from the SuperUser crowd.

What I want to do is make it so that the 'furthest page read' feature either resets, or re-syncs to the page that I currently want to be on.

Comment: Arrived here after clicking a link in an introduction that linked to a footnote on the last page of a book. God dammit.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=84601:

1) Set the Synchronization off on the amazon
Go to Amazon -> Your Account -> Manage You Kindle -> Manage Kindle Device Synchronization -> click the "Turn the Synchronization off" button to turn off the synchronization

2) Exit & re-enter your book. Go to the begging of your book on your kindle and try to sync the furtherest position. It should say that you're currently on your furthest location.

3) Turn on the synchornization setting on the Amazon

4) Exit & re-enter your book.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of an old question, but Amazon have now added a feature to the Manage My Kindle page.

Go to 'Your Kindle Library' and locate the book you wish to reset. The Actions button now has an option to 'Clear further page read'

This is only for books purchased via Amazon, it does not work for Personal Documents you may have emailed to your Kindle.